# Unicode tooltips not showing up

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, tooltip

I am trying to display unicode tooltips in my application window, however they do not seem to display.  Non-unicode text shows up correctly but as soon as I try doing unicode no tooltip shows up.  The following is what I am currently doing, any help is appreciated thank you.

```
     HWND parentHwnd = pickInfo->getViewer().getCachedHwnd();
  CWnd *pWnd = CWnd::FromHandlePermanent(parentHwnd);
  HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

  if (isUnicode)
   m_toolInfoW.lpszText = L"This tooltip does not show up at all.";
  else
   m_toolInfoA.lpszText = "Non unicode text";

  if (!m_bTooltipInitialized){
   ::SendMessage(m_tooltipHwnd, WM_DESTROY, 0,0);

   if(isUnicode)
    m_tooltipHwnd = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_TOPMOST,
     TOOLTIPS_CLASSW, NULL,
     WS_POPUP | TTS_NOPREFIX | TTS_ALWAYSTIP,  
     CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
     CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
     parentHwnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
   else 
    m_tooltipHwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST,
     TOOLTIPS_CLASS, NULL,
     WS_POPUP | TTS_NOPREFIX | TTS_ALWAYSTIP,  
     CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
     CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
     parentHwnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

   if (GetLastError() != 0)
    return;

   ::SetWindowPos(m_tooltipHwnd, HWND_TOPMOST,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);

   // Set the max text width before multi-line tooltip is used.
   ::SendMessage(m_tooltipHwnd, TTM_SETMAXTIPWIDTH, 0, m_nMaxWinTooltipWidth);

   if (isUnicode){
    m_toolInfoW.uFlags = TTF_SUBCLASS | TTF_IDISHWND | TTF_TRACK;
    m_toolInfoW.hinst = hInstance;
    m_toolInfoW.hwnd = parentHwnd;
    m_toolInfoW.uId = (UINT_PTR)parentHwnd;
    ::GetClientRect (parentHwnd, &m_toolInfoW.rect);

    ::SendMessage(m_tooltipHwnd, TTM_ADDTOOLW, 0, (LPARAM) (LPTOOLINFOW) &m_toolInfoW);
    ::SendMessage(m_tooltipHwnd, TTM_ACTIVATE, TRUE, (LPARAM)(LPTOOLINFOW) &m_toolInfoW);
   }
   else{
    m_toolInfoA.uFlags = TTF_SUBCLASS | TTF_IDISHWND;
    m_toolInfoA.hinst = hInstance;
    m_toolInfoA.hwnd = parentHwnd;
    m_toolInfoA.uId = (UINT_PTR)parentHwnd;
    ::GetClientRect (parentHwnd, &m_toolInfoA.rect);

    ::SendMessage(m_tooltipHwnd, TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM) (LPTOOLINFO) &m_toolInfoA);
    ::SendMessage(m_tooltipHwnd, TTM_ACTIVATE, TRUE, (LPARAM)(LPTOOLINFO) &m_toolInfoA);
   }
   m_bTooltipInitialized = true;
  }

  if (isUnicode)
   ::SendMessage(m_tooltipHwnd, TTM_UPDATETIPTEXTW, 0, (LPARAM) (LPTOOLINFOW) &m_toolInfoW);
  else
   ::SendMessage(m_tooltipHwnd, TTM_UPDATETIPTEXT, 0, (LPARAM) (LPTOOLINFO) &m_toolInfoA);

  //Repaint the screen so that the area beneath the previous location of the tooltip is restored correctly.
  ::UpdateWindow(pWnd->GetParentOwner()->GetSafeHwnd());
  pWnd = NULL;
```

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that you try to use common controls version 6, but you does not get to use it.

More in details,

```
typedef struct tagTOOLINFOW {
    UINT cbSize;
    UINT uFlags;
    HWND hwnd;
    UINT_PTR uId;
    RECT rect;
    HINSTANCE hinst;
    LPWSTR lpszText;
    LPARAM lParam;
#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WINXP)
    void *lpReserved;
#endif
} TTTOOLINFOW, NEAR *PTOOLINFOW, *LPTTTOOLINFOW;
```

for xp+, the header file CommCtrl.h assume you'll use comctl version 6, but if you does not enable it **explictly** with manifest file, you'll still use the old comctl version 5.x. Then here comes the problem, the size of TOOLINFO of version 5.x is different to version 6.x.

So if you need to use comctl version 5 under windows xp+, you should init TOOLINFO with follwing code,

```
TOOLINFO ti;
ti.cbSize = sizeof(TOOLINFO) - 4;
```

Otherwise, you should enable visual-style look with manifest file or prgram directive:

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

Finally, I'd recommand you always enable visual-look in xp+. Here are the comparision of visual effects:

[image: common controls 5.x]

[image: common controls 6.x]

Note: If you use ANSI/MBCS to compile the program, the sizeof(TOOLINFO) will be 48, which have already remove the lpReserved member. So ANSI version would works, but UNICODE would fail.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm trying simple tooltip sample code from MSDN with VS2008 on Windows 7, but quickly encounter the problem that ANSI build shows up the tooltip but Unicode build never does. Sending TTM_ADDTOOL returns 0(fail). I come to your post by Googling and got the exact answer. What a big prit from Microsoft! But I can't still explain why ANSI build does not trigger the error. If M$ comctl32 pre-6.0 code checks for an incompatible `TOOLINFO.cbSize` from the caller, both ANSI and Unicode should exhibit the same behavior.

Comment: What a life saver! And also a small notes, remember to subtract `8` if compiling for x64. Actually just do `.cbSize = sizeof(TOOLINFO) - sizeof(void*)`, if you are NOT using that `pragma` thing

Answer (score 2):

Good explanation and a solution that will work by Jichao above, but hard-wiring the size of the TOOLINFO structure will fix only the tooltips.  If the problem is that the program was compiled with common controls 6.0+ in mind, but may be run on (say) a Windows XP system with 6.0+ either not installed, or not fully installed (like someone installed IE, but never used or updated it), then the more general solution is to restrict the application to using only 5.x common controls.

As can be seen [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298349(v=vs.85).aspx), there are more things that have structure size changes than just tooltips.

What I did to insure that everything would work on Windows XP is put the following at the very top of my program, before any includes (in the case of visual studio, a good place would be at the top of targetver.h if you have one):

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT    0x0500
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Unicode case you have `TTF_TRACK`, which I believe requires you to manually show or hide the tooltip.  In the ANSI case, you don't have that option.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760252(VS.85).aspx

Scroll down to "Implementing Tracking Tooltips".

Comment: Thanks for noticing that.  You are right that should not be there, I forgot to remove it when I was testing things out.  However that does not solve my problem.  Without that flag there is still not tooltip showing up.

Comment: Is the parent window Unicode as well?  Perhaps there's an incompatibility between using a Unicode tooltip with an ANSI parent window.