# POPUP Window on WM_MOUSEHOVER in WIN32 API - how to close it?

Tags: winapi, popup, mouseevent, mousehover

I am relatively novice in WIN32 API and have problems with the code shown below, which is from my WinProc function: I use TrackMouseEvent with TME_HOVER to get a WM_MOUSEHOVER when the mouse cursor stays for a while in my window. This works if I call TrackMouseEvent on each WM_MOUSEMOVE, but not if I call in only once somewhere else. Why? (this is the 1st question)

When I receive WM_MOUSEHOVER I create a POPUP window, which I can see, and call again TrackMouseEvent for TME_LEAVE. This works and I receive WM_MOUSELEAVE when the mouse cursor leaves my window, then I want to hide and destroy the popup window (the HWND of which I stored in a static variable) but this does not work, the popup windows stays there. Why? (this is the 2nd question)

Can anybody give me an example or link to a simple example showing TrackMouseEvent and PopUp windows? Many Thanks.

```
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    {
        TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme;
        tme.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
        tme.dwFlags = TME_HOVER;
        tme.hwndTrack = hSBox;
        TrackMouseEvent(&tme);
    }
    break;

case WM_MOUSEHOVER:
    {
        hPop = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_STATICEDGE, //WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                              TEXT("STATIC"),
                              TEXT("pop-up"),
                              WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER, 
                              100, 100, 100, 100,
                              hWnd, (HMENU)0, hInstance, NULL);
        ShowWindow(hPop, SW_SHOW);

        TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme;
        tme.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
        tme.dwFlags = TME_LEAVE;
        tme.hwndTrack = hSBox;
        TrackMouseEvent(&tme);
    }
    return 0;

case WM_MOUSELEAVE:
    {
       ShowWindow(hPop, SW_HIDE);
       DestroyWindow(hPop);
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: Why not create window only once, and shows at hover/hide at leave ?

Comment: Interesting objection, I guess that means to use TOOLTIPS_CLASS?
Nevertheless with the code show here you may have more control over the text shown and can change it better dinamically? I don't know.

Comment: Well, better said, your comment is obviously correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems that I can see:

Your problem with `TME_HOVER` is because you're not initialising the `dwHoverTime` member; you should set it to `HOVER_DEFAULT`. Otherwise the hover timeout will be set to whatever random value is on the stack.

Your second problem is that each call to `TrackMouseEvent` overrides the previous one. Because you're calling `TrackMouseEvent` on every `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message, the `TME_LEAVE` call is quickly being overridden by your next `TME_HOVER` call.

The solution to this is to use some sort of flag in your `WM_MOUSEMOVE` handler, so that you only call `TrackMouseEvent` once, when the mouse first enters your window. Tracking is cancelled when you get the `WM_MOUSEHOVER` and `WM_MOUSELEAVE` messages, so at those points you'd reset the flag so that next time you get `WM_MOUSEMOVE` you can start it again if necessary.

```
// note: BOOL g_fMouseTracking needs to be declared in the same place
// hPop is

case  WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    if (!g_fMouseTracking && !hPop)
    {
        // start tracking if we aren't already
        TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme;
        tme.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
        tme.dwFlags = TME_HOVER | TME_LEAVE;
        tme.hwndTrack = hSBox;
        tme.dwHoverTime = HOVER_DEFAULT;
        g_fMouseTracking = TrackMouseEvent(&tme);
    }
    break;

case  WM_MOUSEHOVER:
    g_fMouseTracking = FALSE; // tracking now cancelled
    if (!hPop)
    {
        hPop = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_STATICEDGE, //WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                              TEXT("STATIC"),
                              TEXT("pop-up"),
                              WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER, 
                              100, 100, 100, 100,
                              hWnd, (HMENU)0, hInstance, NULL);
        ShowWindow(hPop, SW_SHOW);

        // set up leave tracking
        TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme;
        tme.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
        tme.dwFlags = TME_LEAVE;
        tme.hwndTrack = hSBox;
        g_fMouseTracking = TrackMouseEvent(&tme);
    }
    return 0;

case  WM_MOUSELEAVE:
    g_fMouseTracking = FALSE; // tracking now cancelled
    if (hPop)
    {
        // close popup if it's open
       ShowWindow(hPop, SW_HIDE);
       DestroyWindow(hPop);
       hPop = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, your modified code worked perfectly!
Not HOVER_DEFAULT was my problem (I had it, although not in the code I pasted here) but the missing check "if (!g_fMouseTracking && !hPop)" was my problem.

Comment: And also Thanks for this example on how commenting better the source code

Answer (score 3):

By the way, I also found that what I want to do can also be done with windows TOOLTIPS_CLASS.

The most recommendable link I found for this are:

http://winapi.foosyerdoos.org.uk/info/common_cntrls.php#CreateTooltip

https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/master/dlls/comctl32/tooltips.c

[Unicode tooltips not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545682/unicode-tooltips-not-showing-up)